# How to Add an element at the back of the array using arrow function

Tags: javascript, function, push

```
const addLast = (element) => {
  return (arr) => {
    
  };
};
```

Add an element at the back of the array.

Arguments
element (any): The element to add.

Returns
(Array) => Array: Returns a closure that will create a copy of the array with the new element at back.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Are you trying to add an element to the end? then use array.push(item).

Comment: Using this? [...array, array[last_position_elemnt]]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want, try this:

```js
const addLast = (element) => {
    return (arr) =>{
        let array = arr.slice(1,arr.length);
        array.push(element);
        return array;
    }
}
```